# Angular cli very slow in my ubuntu 16

Tags: angular-cli

I am using angular cli latest version beta - 17. It freezes very often especially when recompiling after file change. Any suggestions on how to deal with this?

I am using ubuntu 16 ***.

Comment: Freezes? What does it exactly mean?

Comment: A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.

Script: http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:29409

Comment: This browser message looks strange. Do you use a standard browser (eg. Firefox, Chromium, etc.)? Does your computer have enough free memory?

Comment: There is enough memory and yes I use standard browsers. What would u suggest?

Comment: Sorry, no other ideas at the moment.